# UItextfield not rendering background color

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uicolor

When UITextfield is visible on viewdidload method, It's background color is visible. However, If the text field is kept hidden until some event occurs, It's background color is not visible.
In the image, I have given text field white color background with an alpha value. 
In first case color is visible, however in the second case, background color seems to be the clear color.

These text fields are inside UIStackView.

[image: Transparent Background color]
[image: Visible Background Color]

Comment: Please share your code so we have something to debug

Comment: You can download the sample project from here, which is having the exact same issue. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4t7fklqnqon8zi/testfield.zip?dl=0

Comment: Also, This issue appears only with the text field which is not visible at the time of loading. 
This issue has something to do with UIStackView. Taking out fields out of UIStackView resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When textfield is in stackView call

```
  self.field1.isHidden = false

  self.field1.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: I have programatically added the color. Both of textfields have same custom  class.
Ideally They should look exacty same

Comment: By default isHidden = true clear the background color or dem display

Comment: Here's the sample project. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4t7fklqnqon8zi/testfield.zip?dl=0
Issue can be checked in this project. Also If we takeout textfields outside of UIStackView, issue is automatically fixed

Comment: Call setNeedsDisplay